# Automatic Apple TestFlight upload

Tags: ios, testflight

Now that Apple is shutting down (the old) TestFlight, I've started to look at their own TestFlight implementation.

Is there any way to submit a binary to Apple via a script? Maybe via "Application Loader"? I'd like to integrate this into a CI system.

**Edit:** I was able to control Application Loader via AppleScript and an unfinished version of the script is here: https://gist.github.com/maciekish/88fb6935c3d2a213b1d2

The new question is how can i build an .ipa file to give to Application Loader in a post archive script?

Comment: Regarding your edit to produce an .IPA file - have you taken a look at the `xcodebuild` command line tool?

Comment: You should be able to do something with AppleScript and Application Loader.

Comment: I can't speak to the functionality or workability, but I did find [this](http://diegopeinador.blogspot.dk/2013/10/automatic-app-creation-and-binary-upload.html)  Let us know how it works in a comment :)

Comment: Reading the article referred by @David there's a link to http://fastlane.tools/ in the comments which seems to do what you want and more...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Both [fastlane](https://fastlane.tools) and [nomad](http://nomad-cli.com) provide excellent command-line resources for building & uploading binaries (among other things).

Comment: One year on, are these still the best options? It looks like they are still in active development so thanks for the original answer :)

Comment: Fastlane is the best option these days.

Answer (score 14):

I struggled a lot and finally I configured TeamCity and TestFlight and uploaded generated IPA from team city onto test flight using following script. This is Application Loader command line tool

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Applications/Application\ Loader.app/Contents/Frameworks/ITunesSoftwareService.framework/Support/altool --upload-app -f %system.teamcity.build.workingDir%/Build/IPA/**IPA_NAME**.ipa -u '**TESTFLIGHT_USER_NAME**' -p '**TESTFLIGHT_PASSWORD**'
```

Comment: This should be marked as the correct answer, `altool` is build-in and supported by Apple, various 3rd party tools add a lot of complexity for very little benefit.

Answer (score 3):

I know it's completely outdated, but for those who come across this post in the future.

Yes you can automate the upload process by using the Application Loader command-line tool called altool:

http://help.apple.com/itc/apploader/#/apdATD1E53-D1E1A1303-D1E53A1126

The syntax for uploading the .ipa file is:

altool --upload-app -f [path_to_file] -u [username] -p [password]

This tool requires a Mac, but you can always rent a mac from macincloud.com (not related) and automate the process with a CI server like Jenkins or so.

Comment: This is not outdated. `altool` is the correct and Apple-supported command. You can read about it [under “Upload tools” in the App Store Connect documentation](https://developer.apple.com/help/app-store-connect/reference/upload-tools), as well as Apple’s [detailed `altool` usage guide](https://help.apple.com/asc/appsaltool/).

Answer (score 2):

Apple has published APIs for app store connect. By using these APIs you can automate TestFlight related operations like add/delete testers or submit build for review etc. You can find more details here:
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appstoreconnectapi/testflight